# Prove $\int_{-\infty}^a F(x) d x=\int_a^{\infty}(1-F(x)) d x$ If and only if a = µ

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a continous random variable with distribution function F(x), the aim is to proof that the following equality:

$\int_{-\infty}^a F(x) d x=\int_a^{\infty}(1-F(x)) d x$

Holds if and only if a = µ, where µ is the mean of X.

I'm having real trouble trying to proof it:

Assuming a=µ, I used the definition of the mean: $\mu=\int x f(x) d x$ (from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ ), where $f(x)$ is the density function corresponding to $F(x)$, and by definition $f(x)=F'(X)$.

Now I thought it will be interesting to split $\mu$ into the sum two integrals, one from $-\infty$ to $\mu$ and the other from $\mu$ to $\infty$. Then taking advantage of the way $\mu$ its defined it is easy to do integration by parts and we get:

$\mu= xF(x)\Big|_{-\infty}^\mu - \int_{-\infty}^\mu F(x) d x + xF(x)\Big|_\mu^{\infty} - \int_\mu^{-\infty} F(x) d x$.

Now I have one of the integrals involved in the statement so I think is nice, I've been playing around with this expresion but seems that I'm not getting progress.

Didn't tried yet the reverse implication since I'm quite frustated, any kind of help will be nice. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.*
Try to take the integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^a F(x) \, dx$ by parts $u=F(x)$ and $dv = dx$. Consider an equation
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^a F(x) \, dx - \int\limits_{a}^{+\infty} \big(1-F(x)\big) \, dx = 0.
$$
Also you need to prove that $xF(x) \to 0$ as $x\to-\infty$ and $x(1-F(x)) \to 0$ as $x\to+\infty$.